# How to align labels within Frame in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am learning tkinter labels and I am trying to replicate pycharm community edition screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RSMy.png)

I have below questions-

1. How to add space between 'Version 2019.3.4' and 'New project' without frames. Meaning I need to add space lines between two labels
2. I need to right align my 3 labels within frame - '+Create New Project' , 'Open' , 'Get From Version Control'
3. Is there anyway I can add icons using url like https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_icons_code.asp

Here is my working code -

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#WidthxHeight
root.geometry('733x434')

root.configure(bg="white")

root.title(" Welcome to PyCharm")



Label(root,text='PC',bg="Black",fg="White",font="Verdana 15",underline=0).pack(side=TOP)

Label(root,text='PyCharm Community Edition',bg="White",fg="Black",font="Verdana 12").pack()

Label(root,text='Version 2019.3.4',bg="White",fg="Black",font="Verdana 9").pack()

frame = Frame(root,bg="white",pady=35)
frame.pack()

Label(frame,text='+Create New Project',bg="White",fg="Black",font="Verdana 9").pack()

Label(frame,text='Open',bg="White",fg="Black",font="Verdana 9").pack()

Label(frame,text='Get From Version Control',bg="White",fg="Black",font="Verdana 9").pack()


bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

l2=Label(bottomframe,text='Get Help',bg="White",fg="Black",font="Verdana 9").pack(side=RIGHT)

l1=Label(bottomframe,text='Configure',bg="White",fg="Black",font="Verdana 9").pack(side=RIGHT)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have already known how to use `pady=35` to separate the version and *New Project* labels, so what is your issue actually? For the right alignment, add `anchor="e"` to those `.pack()` on the 3 labels.

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: @acw1668 I want to know how can i do the below -

Label1

<2 line of space>
Label2


<3line of spaces>

with padx and pady it adds spaces on both up and down side of the label. In html we have tab or nbsp to add line line spaces. i want to understand how i can do that

Comment: You can pass a tuple of 2 values to `pady` in `pack()`, like `pack(pady=(20, 30))`, then it will add 20 pixels above and 30 pixels below the widget.